# JAXB unmarshal XML with element dynamic name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I need read this xml file with JABX when Application began:

```
<local>
  <titles>
    <main>Aplication</main>
    <edit>Change data </edit>
    <price>value of </price>
    <level>your level </level>
  </titles>
  <errors>
    <generic>Generic Error</generic>
    <security>Not Allows</security>
    <data>data error </data>
  </errors>
</local>
```

I tried this code:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Local {

    @XmlAnyElement  private Element titles;
    @XmlAnyElement  private Element errors;
 
    public Element getTitles() { return titles; }
    public Element getErrors() { return errors; } 
}
```

but, I have this error message

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
> javax.lang.model.element.Element field
> swingexample.pojo.Locale.titulos to
> com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl  at
> sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
> at
> sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
> at
> sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
> at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at that code to unmarshall objects with JAXB. I bet you will find everything you need inside it.
Code found on [that example of howtodoinjava.com](https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/jaxb-unmarshaller-example/)

Employee.java

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.model;
 
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
 
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Employee implements Serializable {
 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Department department;
 
    public Employee() {
        super();
    }
 
    //Setters and Getters
 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", department="
                + department + "]";
    }
 
    // It is called immediately after the object is created and before the unmarshalling begins.
    // The callback provides an opportunity to initialize JavaBean properties prior to unmarshalling.
    void beforeUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
        System.out.println("Before Unmarshaller Callback");
    }
 
    // It is called after all the properties are unmarshalled for this object,
    // but before this object is set to the parent object.
    void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
        System.out.println("After Unmarshaller Callback");
    }
}
```

JaxbExample.java

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo;
 
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.Employee;
 
public class JaxbExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String fileName = "employee.xml";
 
        jaxbXmlFileToObject(fileName);
    }
 
    private static void jaxbXmlFileToObject(String fileName) {
         
        File xmlFile = new File(fileName);
         
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try
        {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
             
            Employee employee = (Employee) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
             
            System.out.println(employee);
        }
        catch (JAXBException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

employee.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employee>
    <department>
        <id>101</id>
        <name>IT</name>
    </department>
    <firstName>Lokesh</firstName>
    <id>1</id>
    <lastName>Gupta</lastName>
</employee>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks by help, but the real question is the element name dynamic, then I can receve a xml like:

```
<local>
  <titles>
    <main>Aplication</main>
    <edit>Change data </edit>
    <price>value of </price>
    <level>your level </level>
  </titles>
  <errors>
    <generic>Generic Error</generic>
    <security>Not Allows</security>
    <data>data error </data>
  </errors>
</local>
```

or like:

```
<local>
  <titles>
    <app>Aplication</app>
    <splash>Splash message </splash>
  </titles>
  <errors>
    <err>Generic Error</err>
    <validate>Not valid</validate>
  </errors>
</local>
```

The titles and errors elements are constants, but inside this elements I can receve any kind of element(main, app, edit, ... etc)